# ＲでＣＳＶデータの数値データに前０を付けたい

Tags: r

ＣＳＶデータの数値データに前０を付けたい。1桁の数値に前０を付けたいです。
どなたか教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

数値の「見た目」を変更する目的では、tidyverseに含まれてる
library(stringr)のstr_pad()が便利です。

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

> somedata <- 10
> somedata
[1] 10

> str(somedata) # データはnumeric型
 num 10
```

```
> str_pad(somedata, 6, pad = "0")
[1] "000010"

> str_pad(somedata, 6, pad = "0") %>% str 
 chr "000010"
# データは character 型に変換されている
```

numeric オブジェクトは純粋な数値のみしか保持できませんので
「不要なゼロ」を足すために、character(文字)型に
結果が変換されている事にご留意ください。

最も単純な見分け方は、「結果の出力がダブルクオートで囲まれているか」です。

```
[1] 10
[1] "000010"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速使わせていただきました。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。よろしければ「回答の承認」ボタンを押して頂けますと他の方の参考になります。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers